# How to play audio on website without quicktime?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, quicktime

I checked some themes here, but still can't find answer about next.

On my website, I'm using different ways for audion playing.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $(".audio").prepend($("<embed>").attr({
        'src':'/resources/voices/'+voice+'.wav',
        'HIDDEN':'true',
        'AUTOSTART':'true'
    }));
}else if($.browser.safari){
    $(".audio").removeAttr("style");
    $(".audio").prepend($("<object></object>").attr({
        'type':'audio/x-wav',
        'data':'/resources/voices/'+voice+'.wav',
        'width':'0',
        'height':'0'
    }));
    $("object:first").prepend($("<param>").attr({
        'name':'autoplay',
        'value':'true'
    }));
}else{
    $(".audio").prepend($("<audio></audio>").attr({
        'src':'/resources/voices/'+voice+'.wav',
        'volume':0.4,
        'autoplay':'autoplay'
    }));
}
```

Everything was fine, while some of website guests, said that there was errors connected with quicktime plugin.
And, yes, I installed quicktime from apple.com, and now, audio doesn't play in IE. And in chrome it always asks about confirmation to use quicktime plugin.

Is it possible to ignore quicktime plugin, and use standart ways to play audio?
I'm looking anything from javascript...

Thank you!!!

Comment: how the world survived so long without quicktime? :) why not choose a free format like ogg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), since it uses HTML5 for Playback, but has a Flash-Fallback, in case the Browser doesn't support HTML5 yet.

Comment: You don't understand my situation, the plugins installed on my guests Pcs. I can not control what they have installed.

Comment: You don't need to install JPlayer, you have to embed it inside your HTML

Comment: hmm... I need to check... sounds great

Answer (score 1):

Use a general, not dependent on quicktime encoding format. I recommend [ogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg), which is free.

Comment: But you should. It isn't a good idea to serve WAV on the internet: Either the clients won't use it, as it takes to long to load or your ISP might throttle your server connection, as you use to much bandwidth.

Comment: it will be more difficult to force me and another 1 billion users install quicktime.

Comment: I didn't have any troubles with wav, I used to smallest quality, and size wasn't bad - about 10 kB

Comment: no, this advise arn't working, because quicktime trying to play .ogg

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5 or Flash but in any case you should use proper audio format for that purpose